# Practice shell programming (beginner)

Tags: linux, bash, shell, sh

I have a problem with this code:

```
#! /bin/sh

i=0
while [ $i -lt 5 ] ; do    
  echo $1
  i=$((i + 1))
  sleep 1
done
```

When i run the script as `./boucle_arg.sh 2`, I get the following error:

```
./boucle_arg.sh: line 4: [: missing `]'
```

Comment: The problem is quote clear: `[ 0 -lt` would yield that error. But I don't think the code you posted is actually the code causing that problem.

Comment: His code works on my computer if one changes the shebang -- see my answer.

Comment: Please verify that you're seeing the problem when copy-pasting this code and not when using your own version. People sometimes "clean up" code before posting it, and e.g. changing `while [ $i -lt 5] ; do` to `while [ $i -lt 5 ] ; do` is enough to change the meaning.

Comment: Nothing to do with the error, but did you intend to `echo $1` instead of `echo $i`?

Comment: No it's echo $i sorry but i have the same problem with the modified shebang

Comment: I copied the code "edited" and my script works now. Thanks for help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing the shebang at the beginning to:

```
#!/bin/bash
```

Or, to be even more portable (not all systems have bash at /bin/), you can use this shebang instead:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
```

One more thing: don't forget to make your script executable by running the following (please change the script path to your own script's path):

```
chmod +x /usr/local/bin/script1
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure that `/bin/sh` is linked to `/bin/bash` As the error  in dash and ksh would would be `[: missing ]`.

Comment: OK, good point; I tried on my computer and it works both ways (Debian 8.6, GNU bash, version 4.3.30(1)). So, not sure what the problem is, as it works for me on my system.